# calculating rotation direction between two angles

Tags: trigonometry

Consider the following scenario:

[image]

Say I have a robot positioned at (0,0) and his current angle is 70.

I need an algorithm that given two angles - the current angle and the target angle, will give me a direction where I need to turn - left or right, based on which way is the closest (assume it turns in place). In the example above the output will be right.

I've tried lots calculations, each one had at least one scenario that broke it. these are some potentially problamatic scenarios I thought of:

[image]

output shoud be left.

[image]

output should be right.

[image]

output should be left.

I am not sure if this is the right forum to post this, but it seems to be the simplest thing ever and we have been struggling with this all day ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing this as a pencil-and-paper exercise then of course
you can "see" which way to turn.
The problem, I assume, is when you try to program this into software
(such as a controller for your robot),
and then it becomes a problem that can cause a lot of trouble
when not handled well.

My preferred method for this is:

1. Take $\theta_{\text{provisional}} = \theta_{\text{target}} - \theta_{\text{current}}$.
2. Set $\theta_{\text{turn}} = \begin{cases}
   \theta_{\text{provisional}} 
   & \text{if }\ {-180} < \theta_\text{provisional} \leq 180,\\
   \theta_{\text{provisional}} - 360
   & \text{if }\ \theta_\text{provisional} > 180,\\
   \theta_{\text{provisional}} + 360
   & \text{if }\ \theta_\text{provisional} \leq -180.
   \end{cases}$

Turn left if $\theta_\text{turn} > 0$,
right if $\theta_\text{turn} < 0$.
(The procedure above does a left turn to execute an exact about-face;
if you prefer a right turn, change which inequalities are strict,
such as $<$, and which are non-strict, such as $\leq$.)

I prefer the interval $(-180,180]$ for "turn angles" because it
is obvious that $14$ and $-14$ are turns of the same magnitude but in
opposite directions, whereas it is much less obvious that
$14$ and $346$ are turns of the same magnitude.
Moreover, the sign of the angle indicates the direction of the turn,
just as the signs of many other things (slopes, derivatives,
scalar multiples of vectors, etc.) indicate their directions.

I actually usually use an algorithm that adds or subtracts a whole
*multiple* of $360$ as needed to put the answer in the interval
$[-180, 180]$,
but that's because in the context where I find myself computing turn angles,
I never quite trust the input angles (current and target)
to be themselves given in consistent intervals of angles
(i.e., both in the interval $[0,360)$ or both in the interval $(-180,180]$).
If you can trust your input values to be "clean" in this way
then you do not need to go to this extra trouble.

Comment: It was indeed for the controller for our robot and it worked!!! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2):

Take $\Delta$ = target - current (if it is negative, then add 360 until it is in the range 0 to 360)

Now if it is above 180 it is right, and if it is below 180 then it is left